# 21 Reputation—not able to chat

Tags: support, chat, privileges

I have **21 reputation**, yet going to the Mathematics chat shows me the message that I must have at least 20 reputation.

Update:
*There is a contradiction!*

- A notification reads that I have the privilege to participate in chat.
- When I go to the chat and click my avatar, I see that my reputation is only 11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those numbers aren't updated in real time; it may take up to an hour to reflect the change. I've force-updated your chat account, so have fun chatting now :)

Comment: Hi, I apologise if this isn't a suitable place to ask this, but since about half an hour ago I haven't been able to use the chat, the reason given being that I don't have enough reputation. However I have 425 reputation which should be sufficient. Could you help me?

Comment: @mr.FS To be honest with you, I have no idea why you turned out with zero reputation on chat. But I have refreshed your profile and it's fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem I don't suppose it was your fault :). Thanks for fixing it.